# SSD adapter for optical drive

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, ssd, hardware-recommendation

I'm going to add a SSD drive to my macbook pro.
I'm wondering if the optical drive adapter can have any influence on the disk speed, taking it down from a SATA III to a SATA II or I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding SATA I, II and III and getting the best speeds speeds — it really depends on what specification your machine is, and what adapter you get.

I would suggest you **install the SSD in place of your original HDD**, that way you don't lose out on the SSD's potential because of an adapter:

- MacBook Pros from Early 2011 and onwards do have SATA III (6 Gbit/s) connectors for their main HDD compartment.
- But ones from Mid 2010 and before have SATA II (3 Gbit/s).

In either case, I would install the SSD there, and then **install the HDD in the optical bay**, because:

- From what I know, newer MacBook Pros support SATA III in their SuperDrive bay — so to take advantage of it, you'll need to get an optical bay adapter bracket that supports it too.
- MacBook Pros from around 2011 (and older) have SATA II in the optical bay.

To find out what you have, go to Spotlight (the magnifying glass in the top-right of your screen), and type "System Information", open that app, go to `Hardware > Serial-ATA > Link Speed` and it should say there.