# Main partition on original Apple SSD or new Samsung PRO SSD in 2011 Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

[A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74495/issues-with-installing-ssd-instead-of-dvd-drive) [few](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73357/is-installing-a-hdd-instead-of-superdrive-safe) [questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72497/ssd-adapter-for-optical-drive) [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25224/optimize-macbook-pro-for-internal-ssdhdd-drives?rq=1) relate to replacing the optical drive with an additional HD or SSD. Its time for this to happen on my MBP 15 inch (late 2011).

So I will effectively have:

- the original 256gb SSD where it was when I got the macbook
- a new Samsung 840 Pro SSD in the DVD compartment

My question: which disk would you expect to fail sooner? I'm trying to decide where toput my OS and where to put my home directory etc...  Any thoughts or experience are helpful!

Comment: My suggestion is to consider a real solid backup plan. At one point, any of your SSD drives is going to fail.

Comment: Have you checked that you can run any of the SDDs in the optical drive bay? 2011 mbps seem to only run reliably when the optical drive has a drive that connects at SATA II speeds.

Comment: Yes @myhd - I have Drobos and Dropbox set up appropriately.

Comment: @xpereta - thanks for the heads up. Do you know where I can find the precise details regarding this? The 840 Pro is now in the DVD slot of the macbook and I can copy to-from it without a hitch. In System Information "link speed" and negotiated link speed" are 6Gigabit. Does that mean I am safe? Or is there a way I can test this? Thanks for your help!!

Comment: How to actualy test it is an interesting question. Why don't you ask it in a separate question? Even though you can use the drive there may be errors happening during the transmission of data that could reduce the drive performance or even worse could corrupt the data.

Comment: Done - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123440/ssd-instead-of-dvd-testing-its-reliability

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this question can be answered with authority.

However, if you are worried about failure due to memory cells wear, we can speculate. Every thing else being equal I would expect the SDD disk to last longer. That's because the SSD controller tends to spread writes among the available memory cells, and the more cells available the less writes each cell will receive.

And of course I would expect a new drive to fail later than an old and used drive.

Then I would say that generaly speaking a newer and bigger SSD will last longer than an older and smaller one.