# Replacing DVD with SSD - What is the best way to test SSD reliability?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata

There have been some reports of specific SSD versions/speeds not working appropriately in specific MacBooks.  Depending for example on SATA chipset etc.  (e.g. saga-3 drives in old early 2011 MBP?).

If the SSD does appear on the desktop and seems to be functioning correctly based on copying a few files back and forth - is there a good way of fully evaluating its reliability? 
(I'm not talking about speed - I'm talking about risk of corruption due to hardware incompatibility)

Comment: A good answer would provide a tool or script to verify that the data being written to the SSD is not corrupted in any wat.

Answer (score 2):

I installed a Samsung 840 Pro 120GB in my Early 2011 MBP.

I have had no issues with it so far.

[DriveDx](http://binaryfruit.com/drivedx) is a good tool which gives health statistics on an SSD and I would also make sure you are running [Trim Enabler](http://www.cindori.org/software/trimenabler/) which will prolong the SSDs life.

As said in other answer stick to big name brands and generally stay away from OCZ or Kingston as they have been reported to fail more often.

Comment: Thanks @Jacob - I wasn't sure whether Trim Enabler should be added on a samsung pro drive. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

i had a seagate ssd in my 2011 mbp and recently replaced it for a bigger samsung ssd,
both work perfect and are very fast. 
I have not noticed any decrease in speed or size in my time using them, so I would advise to stick to the main brands if you are planning to buy one since they offer good warranty and reliable products.